# AnyLogic: Variables from Simulation will not be displayed anymore

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have added some variables in my simulation start page. Now I want to access them from the main class. However, with `((Simulation)getExperiment()).[...]` the variables are no longer displayed. When I press `option+space` only one of about 150 variables is displayed. This one variable is not different from the other variables in the properties.

All variables are on public and I was able to access all of them a few weeks ago. Now not anymore, although I didn't change much in the model. I have already tried restarting. Did I accidentally remove some package or something? Can someone help me here please? I have only noticed the problem now as my model has runtime errors, presumably as the now unrecognized variables are not being initiated.

Pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Share some screenshots of the setup, hard to help otherwise :)

Comment: Hard to explain, even with the pictures I added above... with the combination 'option+tab' on MacOS it should be possible to autocomplete the variable. Unfotunately this is not working. Just ONE varbiable works, but that one variable is no different to the one I showed in my picture. Very strange in my opinion. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access variables from experiments on `Main`. If you need access, you should pass them on as parameters into `Main`.

If you have hundreds of variables in the experiment, turn them into fields in a single Java class. Pass 1 instance of that Java class into `Main` as a parameter.

This way, you always have access, it is easy to add more variables, it is easy to change them and you do not need the awkward (and bad) type-casting you currently do

Comment: Okay thanks Ben, didn't know that this is a bad way to typecast, but I knew there would be an easier way to access them. :)

Comment: it's bad because you might have different experiment types in the future :) Glad it helped